# Display Json Object in React from an API

Tags: javascript, json, api, reactjs

I can display the twitter one but the person object i can't

[image]

I tried this:

```
comps=comps.map(function(comp,index){
return(
    <div key={index}>
Twitter : <a href={comp.twitter}>{comp.twitter}</a> // this one work
Person Name:<span className="PersonneName">{comp.person.nameP}</span> // not working
</div>
);
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person` is an array, so you will likely want to `.map()` over it as well. Your code might look something like this.

```
comps=comps.map(function(comp,index){
return(
    <div key={index}>
Twitter : <a href={comp.twitter}>{comp.twitter}</a> // this one work
Person Name: {comp.person.map(val => {
  return <span className="PersonneName">{val.nomP}</span> 
})}
</div>
);
});
```

However, you're obviously going to return multiple people here. Depending on what you want to do, just handle the array appropriately.

Comment: i can do that for the jobP and depuis ? @Christopher Messer

Comment: On the array i Have 3 objects i want to display all of them

Comment: yes - `val.jobP` and `val.depuis` will work as you expect inside of the second `.map()`

Comment: that's not working the way i want,it diplay me 
all the name near each other.
i want name + job + depuis 
name+job+depuis
name+job+depuis

sorry to bother you

Comment: ````comps=comps.map(function(comp,index){
return(
    <div key={index}>
Twitter : <a href={comp.twitter}>{comp.twitter}</a> 

Person Name: {comp.person.map(val => {
  return <span className="PersonneName">{val.nomP} {val.jobP} {val.depuis} </span> 
})}
</div>
);
});````